# Absolute path for assets in email without having a request object in Symfony2

Tags: email, symfony, twig, assets

I'm sending emails using a Symfony2 command that is triggered by a cron job periodically. In the footer of the email I want to show the logo of the company. I know that in the case of emails, I have to use absolute paths for the images, and normally I would do something like this:

```
{% set abs_url = app.request.scheme ~'://' ~ app.request.httpHost %}
<img src="{{ abs_url ~ asset('bundles/common/images/logo_mialarma.png') }}">
```

But when the twig template of the email is being called by a command that is in turn called by a cron job, there isn't such request object.

How can I create the absolute path of the asset in this situation?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Create a configuration parameter to set your app's domain to.

Comment: You mean something like `app_domain: http://www.bcubo.com` in twig -> globals (config.yml) and then in the template `{{ app_domain ~ asset(...) }}`?

Comment: Yea, that'll do. Although I wouldn't hardcode the `http` part in it.

Answer (score 1):

If someone is using a newer version, see here:

https://symfony.com/doc/current/console/request_context.html

You can set the Context and use global configs.

Answer (score -1):

**try this in twig file:**

`{{ 'http://' ~ app.request.host }}`